# Не работает DNS vestacp

Tags: ubuntu, apache, ethernet, vesta

Установил vestacp на сервер ubuntu, по инструкции все делал и все работает за исключением dns-имен для сервера.
Вот конфиги apacha:

```html
server {
    listen      85.118.114.467:80;
    server_name test.dev.ru www.test.dev.ru;
    error_log  /var/log/apache2/domains/test.dev.ru.error.log error;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://85.118.114.467:8080;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot|eps|ps|zip|tar|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|7z|aac|m4a|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|wma|3gp|avi|flv|m4v|mkv|mov|mpeg|mpg|wmv|exe|iso|dmg|swf)$ {
            root           /home/admin/web/test.dev.ru/public_html;
            access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/test.dev.ru.log combined;
            access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/test.dev.ru.bytes bytes;
            expires        max;
            try_files      $uri @fallback;
        }
    }

    location /error/ {
        alias   /home/admin/web/test.ru/document_errors/;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass      http://85.119.144.216:8080;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
    location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}

    include /home/admin/conf/web/nginx.test.ru.conf*;
}
```

Если захожу по ip 85.118.114.467 то все ок, открывается та страница которая нужна. Если захожу по доменному имени test.dev.ru то "Не удается получить доступ к сайту..." В чем проблема подскажите пожалуйста??

Comment: а в какой ip-адрес резолвится имя `test.dev.ru` на том компьютере, где вы запускаете браузер?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Работаю удаленно с сервером ubuntu по sh. А как проверить это?

Comment: например, выполните команду `$ ping test.dev.ru` **на том компьютере**, где у вас запущен браузер.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin на этот ip 176.9.7.107

Comment: и чего же вы тогда хотите от вашего браузера? чтобы имя резолвилось в `85.118.114.467` (замечательный ip-адрес, кстати)? это не его дело, естественно. воспользуйтесь, например, файлом [hosts](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо, сорян за глупые вопросы может, но я первый день все это дело осваиваю